# ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended on Table Alias

Tags: sql, oracle

Having issues getting this to work.  Each query works individually however when I try to alias each Subquery to work the Join I get the error:

SQL Command not properly ended.  Any suggestions would be extremely appreciated.

```
Select C.* 
From 
    (
        (
            Select 
                a.*,
                Row_Number() Over(Partition By referral_id Order By start_date,line) as rn 
            from hcclsc.referral_Bed_Day a
        ) A
        Inner Join (
            Select
                a.referral_id,
                max(rn) as vn
            From (
                Select
                    referral_id,
                    line,
                    bed_day_type_id,
                    start_date,
                    end_date,
                    Row_Number() Over(Partition by referral_id Order By start_date, line) as rn
                From HCCLSC.referral_Bed_Day 
            ) a
            Group by referral_id
        ) B
        On A.referral_ID = B.referral_id and a.rn = b.vn
    ) C
```

Comment: You're joining `A` to `B`, but then not selecting a anything from those joined subqueries. Which columns are you trying to retrieve from each subquery?

Answer (score 1):

You're joining A to B, but then not selecting a anything from those joined subqueries.

This part:

```
Select C.* 
From 
    (
        (
```

would need to specify columns to select from the join; if you want all of them from both subqueries then:

```
Select C.* 
From 
    (
        Select *
        From
            (
```

but then that extra level of subquery isn't really adding anything, and you can remove the `C` level:

```
Select * 
From 
    (
        Select 
            a.*,
            Row_Number() Over(Partition By referral_id Order By start_date,line) as rn 
        from hcclsc.referral_Bed_Day a
    ) A
    Inner Join (
        Select
            a.referral_id,
            max(rn) as vn
        From (
            Select
                referral_id,
                line,
                bed_day_type_id,
                start_date,
                end_date,
                Row_Number() Over(Partition by referral_id Order By start_date, line) as rn
            From HCCLSC.referral_Bed_Day 
        ) a
        Group by referral_id
    ) B
    On A.referral_ID = B.referral_id and a.rn = b.vn
```

Answer (score 0):

try like below by using cte

```
with cte as
(
Select
    a.referral_id
    max(rn) as vn
    From
        (Select
        referral_id
        ,line
        ,bed_day_type_id
        ,start_date
        ,end_date
        ,Row_Number() Over(Partition by referral_id Order By start_date, line) as rn
        From
        HCCLSC.referral_Bed_Day
    ) a Group by referral_id
), cte2 as
(
Select
    a.*
    ,Row_Number() Over(Partition By referral_id Order By start_date,line) as rn
    from
    hcclsc.referral_Bed_Day a
) select A.*,B.* from cte A join cte2 B 
 on  A.referral_ID = B.referral_id and A.vn= B.rn
```